# How to edit multiple messages in discord python for bot

Tags: python, discord, message, edit

So, I was wondering if I can modify an old message. For example, let's say the bot will have to send two messages.

```
import discord, asyncio

async def test(interaction: discord.Interaction):
   await interaction.response.send_message("Hi! This is the first message.")

   await asyncio.sleep(1)
 
   await interaction.followup.send("This is the second message.")
```

In this case, I know I can modify the last message using interaction.response.editmessage() but that will only change the last message. How can I also modify the first one?

I tried using this:

```
msg = await interaction.response.send_message("Hi! This is the first message.")

await msg.edit()
```

Which doesn't even work.

Also I'm looking to do it with the new discord v2 like not ctx but interaction: discord.Interaction because I'm trying to use this example for a more complex command.

Comment: Edit the message with `original_message` and for the followup you can do `msg = await interaction.followup` and edit it on the normal way.

Comment: Can you explain how original_message works? Because I don't find anything in the documentation of discord.py

Comment: Give me an example of code if possible. Thanks!

Comment: It's now called [original_response](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html?highlight=original_response#discord.Interaction.original_response), my bad. There's also an `edit` method for it.

Comment: That works, but my problem is that I can't use edit_original_response because my original message is sent outside my button callback and what I'm trying to do is edit my original response when I click my button but it gives an error "Webhook not found". Is there a way to like store that message id and then edit it using the message id and also storing the message id as global?